# How do you find Wp7 App Rank without resorting to 3rd Party Apps or Websites

Tags: windows-phone-7

How/Where is the Wp7 AppRank stored/calculated from?  A number of sites and app display it but where are they getting this information from?

A Code example (Its got to be a screenscrape from one of the official sites?) where applicable would be interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Brandon Watson's post on [crawling the Windows Phone Marketplace](http://www.manyniches.com/windows-phone/crawling-the-windows-phone-marketplace/) as a good starting place; http://catalog.zune.net provides xml data on the marketplace, and the information you're looking for (the application rank) can be retrieved through specifying the orderby as downloadRank as he's done, and the first app returned is #1, then #2, etc.

> http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/en-us/apps?clientType=WinMobile%207.1&store=Zest&orderby=downloadRank

Note that this post is a little old, so you may need to play around with the query parameters (like the clientType) to make sure you're getting the right data back. [This post might also be helpful](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-marketplace-your).